# How to fade background when panel is visible in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css

I am working on a project and in that I want to apply background fade feature when a panel opens on a webpage in asp.net. The fade in feature looks like the Facebook photo feature.[click here to see Facebook photo effect](http://screencast.com/t/KYKr22Q96B9P)
Here consider the photo as my panel and background as my web page.

Please help me with this as I don't know what this effect is called.

Comment: This effect is usually called a lightbox or thickbox

Answer (score 1):

It's called an overlay and one way to do it is to append it at the end of your document:

Html:

```
<body>
 ... all your content ...

  <div id="overlay">
     <div class="pictures">
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
   position:relative;
}
#overlay {
    position:absolute; /** or fixed **/
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:none;
}
```

By default your overlay is hidden. you can use JavaScript to set the display to block when the gallery is displayed;

Comment: Thanks lbu..I had to play with the codes but I finally did what I want.